# How to rollback last vendor publish in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hi have messed up my project by doing `vendor` `publish`  here is the `command` last time i have executed   (i'm using **LARAVEL 5.4**)

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

i want to `rollback` to previous state which was there before this `command`

**what i was trying to do:**  i wanted to customize `reset password` `email` template

**Problem:** No longer i'm able to see my customized `forgot password` template and `reset password` template.  but `default template` is appearing for both(`forgot password` and `reset password`).

**Question :**  please help to get my previous state prior to running this `command`   `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: This is what version control is for.

Answer (score 9):

Got it working... The steps to remove a package from Laravel are:

1. Remove declaration from composer.json (in "require" section)
2. Remove Service Provider from "app/config/app.php" (reference in "providers" array)
3. Remove any Class Aliases from "app/config/app.php"
4. Remove any references to the package from your code.
5. Run "composer update vendor/package-name". This will remove the package folder from "vendor" folder and will rebuild composer autoloading map

it will remove the package folder from "Vendor" folder

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 7):

I'm on a similar situation, but with Laravel 5.5 
I think that the rollback in this situations does not exist.

When you execute this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

a folder **vendor/notifications** is created under the **views** folder.

I have delete the **notifications** folder, and executed the command:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

and everything is working fine.

I know that this is an old question, but maybe someone find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `git clean -f -d`

-d: for directory;

-f: for force;

This solved for me.